# Model Trainer Issue on End-to-End ML Project - TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'trained_model_file_path'

Tags: python, machine-learning, machine-learning-model

I am following the process shown on [Wine Quality Prediction End-to-End ML Project](https://youtu.be/pxk1Fr33-L4?si=zqJ_Ice6YT8pLYzJ) on Krish Naik's YouTube channel to do a Flight Fare Prediction Project.

I run this cell of model trainer pipeline on [04_model_trainer.ipynb](https://github.com/MdEhsanulHaqueKanan/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/blob/main/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb):

```
try:
    config = ConfigurationManager()
    model_trainer_config = config.get_model_trainer_config()
    model_trainer_config = ModelTrainer(config=model_trainer_config)
    model_trainer_config.train()
except Exception as e:
    raise e
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'trained_model_file_path'
```

Here is the full traceback:

```
[2023-12-05 08:05:47,529: INFO: common: yaml file: config\config.yaml loaded successfully]
[2023-12-05 08:05:47,544: INFO: common: yaml file: params.yaml loaded successfully]
[2023-12-05 08:05:47,571: INFO: common: yaml file: schema.yaml loaded successfully]
[2023-12-05 08:05:47,573: INFO: common: created directory at: artifacts]
[2023-12-05 08:05:47,578: INFO: common: created directory at: artifacts/model_trainer]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
g:\Machine_Learning_Projects\iNeuron internship\Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project\research\04_model_trainer.ipynb Cell 11 line 7
      <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=4'>5</a>     model_trainer_config.train()
      <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=5'>6</a> except Exception as e:
----> <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=6'>7</a>     raise e

g:\Machine_Learning_Projects\iNeuron internship\Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project\research\04_model_trainer.ipynb Cell 11 line 3
      <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=0'>1</a> try:
      <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=1'>2</a>     config = ConfigurationManager()
----> <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=2'>3</a>     model_trainer_config = config.get_model_trainer_config()
      <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=3'>4</a>     model_trainer_config = ModelTrainer(config=model_trainer_config)
      <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=4'>5</a>     model_trainer_config.train()

g:\Machine_Learning_Projects\iNeuron internship\Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project\research\04_model_trainer.ipynb Cell 11 line 2
     <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=17'>18</a> schema =  self.schema.TARGET_COLUMN
     <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=19'>20</a> create_directories([config.root_dir])
---> <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=21'>22</a> model_trainer_config = ModelTrainerConfig(
     <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=22'>23</a>     root_dir=config.root_dir,
     <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=23'>24</a>     train_data_path = config.train_data_path,
     <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=24'>25</a>     test_data_path = config.test_data_path,
     <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=25'>26</a>     # New Line Added
     <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=26'>27</a>     trained_model_file_path =  os.path.join('artifact', 'model'),
     <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=27'>28</a>     # New Line Ended
     <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=28'>29</a>     model_name = config.model_name,
     <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=29'>30</a>     alpha = params.alpha,
     <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=30'>31</a>     l1_ratio = params.l1_ratio,
     <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=31'>32</a>     target_column = schema.name
     <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=32'>33</a>     
     <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=33'>34</a> )
     <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=35'>36</a> return model_trainer_config

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'trained_model_file_path'
```

Here is the code of `ModelTrainer` class:

```
import os
import sys

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression, Lasso, Ridge, ElasticNet
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor, GradientBoostingRegressor, AdaBoostRegressor
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor

from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

# from ..exception import CustomException
# from ..logger import logging

# from ..utils import save_obj
# from ..utils import evaluate_model   

# from dataclasses import dataclass

# @dataclass
# class ModelTrainerConfig:
#     trained_model_file_path =  os.path.join('artifact', 'model')


class ModelTrainer:

    def __init__(self):
        self.model_trainer_config = ModelTrainerConfig()    


    def save_obj(file_path, obj):
        try:

            dir_path = os.path.dirname(file_path)
            os.makedirs(dir_path, exist_ok=True)

            with open(file_path, 'wb') as file_obj:
                joblib.dump(obj, file_obj, compress= ('gzip'))

        except Exception as e:
            logger.info('Error occured in utils save_obj')
            raise e
        

    def evaluate_model(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, models):

        try:
            report = {}
            for i in range(len(models)):

                model = list(models.values())[i]

                # Train model
                model.fit(X_train,y_train)

                # Predict Testing data
                y_test_pred = model.predict(X_test)

                # Get R2 scores for train and test data
                test_model_score = r2_score(y_test,y_test_pred)

                report[list(models.keys())[i]] =  test_model_score

            return report

        except Exception as e:
            logger.info('Exception occured during model training')
            raise e    



    def initiate_model_training(self, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test):
        try:
            logger.info('Splitting ')

            models={
            'LinearRegression':LinearRegression(),
            'Lasso':Lasso(),
            'Ridge':Ridge(),
            'Elasticnet':ElasticNet(),
            'RandomForestRegressor': RandomForestRegressor(),
            'GradientBoostRegressor()' : GradientBoostingRegressor(),
            "AdaBoost" : AdaBoostRegressor(),
            'DecisionTreeRegressor' : DecisionTreeRegressor(),
            "SupportVectorRegressor" : SVR(),
            "KNN" : KNeighborsRegressor()
            }

            model_report:dict = ModelTrainer.evaluate_model(X_train,y_train, X_test, y_test, models)
            print(model_report)
            print("\n====================================================================================")
            logger.info(f'Model Report : {model_report}')

            # to get best model score from dictionary
            best_model_score = max(sorted(model_report.values()))

            best_model_name = list(model_report.keys())[
                list(model_report.values()).index(best_model_score)
            ]

            best_model = models[best_model_name]

            print(f"Best Model Found, Model Name :{best_model_name}, R2-score: {best_model_score}")
            print("\n====================================================================================")
            logger.info(f"Best Model Found, Model name: {best_model_name}, R2-score: {best_model_score}")
            logger.info(f"{best_model.feature_names_in_}")
            
            ModelTrainer.save_obj(
            file_path = self.model_trainer_config.trained_model_file_path,
            obj = best_model
            )

        except Exception as e:
            logger.info('Exception occured at model trianing')
            raise e
```

Here is [my file in GitHub](https://github.com/MdEhsanulHaqueKanan/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/blob/main/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb).

My file encoding is UTF-8

Would you please help me to fix this issue?

Comment: When initializing `ModelTrainer` you are also including a variable (`ModelTrainer(config=model_trainer_config)`) which is not in the `def __init__` function header, so one of the two things needs to change so that you can either send or not send the variable that you want.

Comment: You already have a definition for ModelTrainerConfig that does not include `trained_model_file_path`.  The stuff you have that's commented out is not going to be read, of course.

Comment: @AndrewRyan Thank you. Your solution has fixed my issue as it always does! You rock!

Comment: @AndrewRyan Please, add your answer. I would love to choose it as the right answer.

Comment: @AndrewRyan Your help is always valuable for me, as it helps me to learn and understand how to fix issues. Would you mind if I reach out to you again if I face issues? And are you available on LinkedIn? I would love to add you there.

Comment: @AndrewRyan I am facing another issue. I posted a question. But got no response from anyone. Would you please take a look at it during your free time?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77613275/model-trainer-issue-on-end-to-end-ml-project-typeerror-init-got-an-unex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error that you are facing is relating to:

```py
class ModelTrainer:
    def __init__(self, model_trainer_config):
        self.model_trainer_config = ModelTrainerConfig()
```

specifically when you call:

```py
    model_trainer_config = ModelTrainer(config=model_trainer_config)
```

When you call ModelTrainer you are saying for the config variable to be updated, which is impossible as there are no config variables in the `ModelTrainer` class. So there are two ways to fix this:

***Option 1:***

Call it it like this:

```py
    model_trainer_config = ModelTrainer(model_trainer_config) # so that you aren't specifying a variable in the class initializer
```

In your current class should be updated like this to actually make use of the variable.

```py
class ModelTrainer:
    def __init__(self, model_trainer_config):
        self.model_trainer_config = model_trainer_config
```

***Option 2:***

Keep it as what you currently have:

```py
    model_trainer_config = ModelTrainer(config=model_trainer_config)
```

But then in your current class should be updated like this to specify the variable (the `:` in a function call is used to specify the type of an object that you should be passing in).

```py
class ModelTrainer:
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.model_trainer_config = config
```

---

Further, you should use the files that are included in the [tutorial](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c7k8i1l2X_r9i4yWAkQzxiP1Nu8_wqap/view), and edit those files for your needs, as there seems to be some differences, which will cause you additional problems likely.

example:

```py
    model_trainer_config = config.get_model_trainer_config() # should be in one variable
    model_trainer_config = ModelTrainer(config=model_trainer_config) # should be in a different variable and not model_trainer_config as train has nothing to do with the config, and is part of the ModelTrainer class 
    model_trainer_config.train()
```