# Model Trainer Issue on End-to-End ML Project - TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'config'

Tags: python, machine-learning, machine-learning-model

I am following the process shown on [Wine Quality Prediction End-to-End ML Project](https://youtu.be/pxk1Fr33-L4?si=zqJ_Ice6YT8pLYzJ) on Krish Naik's YouTube channel to do a Flight Fare Prediction Project.

I run this cell of model trainer pipeline on [04_model_trainer.ipynb](https://github.com/MdEhsanulHaqueKanan/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/blob/main/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb):

```
try:
    config = ConfigurationManager()
    model_trainer_config = config.get_model_trainer_config()
    model_trainer_config = ModelTrainer(config=model_trainer_config)
    model_trainer_config.train()
except Exception as e:
    raise e
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'config'
```

Here is the full traceback:

```
[2023-12-06 09:32:22,134: INFO: common: yaml file: config\config.yaml loaded successfully]
[2023-12-06 09:32:22,141: INFO: common: yaml file: params.yaml loaded successfully]
[2023-12-06 09:32:22,150: INFO: common: yaml file: schema.yaml loaded successfully]
[2023-12-06 09:32:22,153: INFO: common: created directory at: artifacts]
[2023-12-06 09:32:22,157: INFO: common: created directory at: artifacts/model_trainer]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
g:\Machine_Learning_Projects\iNeuron internship\Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project\research\04_model_trainer.ipynb Cell 11 line 7
      <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=4'>5</a>     model_trainer_config.train()
      <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=5'>6</a> except Exception as e:
----> <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=6'>7</a>     raise e

g:\Machine_Learning_Projects\iNeuron internship\Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project\research\04_model_trainer.ipynb Cell 11 line 4
      <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=1'>2</a>     config = ConfigurationManager()
      <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=2'>3</a>     model_trainer_config = config.get_model_trainer_config()
----> <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=3'>4</a>     model_trainer_config = ModelTrainer(config=model_trainer_config)
      <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=4'>5</a>     model_trainer_config.train()
      <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/g%3A/Machine_Learning_Projects/iNeuron%20internship/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb#X12sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=5'>6</a> except Exception as e:

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'config'
```

Here is the code of `ModelTrainer` class:

```
class ModelTrainer:

    def __init__(self, model_trainer_config):
    # def __init__(self):
        self.model_trainer_config = ModelTrainerConfig()    


    def save_obj(file_path, obj):
        try:

            dir_path = os.path.dirname(file_path)
            os.makedirs(dir_path, exist_ok=True)

            with open(file_path, 'wb') as file_obj:
                joblib.dump(obj, file_obj, compress= ('gzip'))

        except Exception as e:
            logger.info('Error occured in utils save_obj')
            raise e
        

    def evaluate_model(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, models):

        try:
            report = {}
            for i in range(len(models)):

                model = list(models.values())[i]

                # Train model
                model.fit(X_train,y_train)

                # Predict Testing data
                y_test_pred = model.predict(X_test)

                # Get R2 scores for train and test data
                test_model_score = r2_score(y_test,y_test_pred)

                report[list(models.keys())[i]] =  test_model_score

            return report

        except Exception as e:
            logger.info('Exception occured during model training')
            raise e    



    def initiate_model_training(self, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test):
        try:
            logger.info('Splitting ')

            models={
            'LinearRegression':LinearRegression(),
            'Lasso':Lasso(),
            'Ridge':Ridge(),
            'Elasticnet':ElasticNet(),
            'RandomForestRegressor': RandomForestRegressor(),
            'GradientBoostRegressor()' : GradientBoostingRegressor(),
            "AdaBoost" : AdaBoostRegressor(),
            'DecisionTreeRegressor' : DecisionTreeRegressor(),
            "SupportVectorRegressor" : SVR(),
            "KNN" : KNeighborsRegressor()
            }

            model_report:dict = ModelTrainer.evaluate_model(X_train,y_train, X_test, y_test, models)
            print(model_report)
            print("\n====================================================================================")
            logger.info(f'Model Report : {model_report}')

            # to get best model score from dictionary
            best_model_score = max(sorted(model_report.values()))

            best_model_name = list(model_report.keys())[
                list(model_report.values()).index(best_model_score)
            ]

            best_model = models[best_model_name]

            print(f"Best Model Found, Model Name :{best_model_name}, R2-score: {best_model_score}")
            print("\n====================================================================================")
            logger.info(f"Best Model Found, Model name: {best_model_name}, R2-score: {best_model_score}")
            logger.info(f"{best_model.feature_names_in_}")
            
            ModelTrainer.save_obj(
            file_path = self.model_trainer_config.trained_model_file_path,
            obj = best_model
            )

        except Exception as e:
            logger.info('Exception occured at model trianing')
            raise e
```

Here is [my file in GitHub](https://github.com/MdEhsanulHaqueKanan/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/blob/main/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb).

My file encoding is UTF-8

Would you please help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Model Trainer Issue on End-to-End ML Project - TypeError: \_\_init\_\_() got an unexpected keyword argument 'trained\_model\_file\_path'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77606532/model-trainer-issue-on-end-to-end-ml-project-typeerror-init-got-an-unex)

Comment: @AndrewRyan No. When I follow that approach, I get this error: `TypeError: __init__() missing 7 required positional arguments: 'root_dir', 'train_data_path', 'test_data_path', 'model_name', 'alpha', 'l1_ratio', and 'target_column' `

Comment: Where is this error coming from?

Comment: @AndrewRyan Sorry for my late response. I was very busy. Now, I am back. The error is coming from this line: `model_trainer_config = ModelTrainer(model_trainer_config)`. Should I create a new question about it?

Comment: @AndrewRyan Hi Andrew, have you got the chance to see my previous message? I am eagerly waiting for your response.

Comment: if you have `self.model_trainer_config = ModelTrainerConfig()` in your class it should be `self.model_trainer_config = model_trainer_config` based on the value that you are passing into the class function. This is because you are not running the `ModelTrainerConfig` because those values have already been created (if you were to run it in that class then you would have to get all of the values and pass that into the function in order to run it that way).

Comment: @AndrewRyan Thank you very much for your great answer and explanation! The issue has been fixed. Please, add it as the answer. I would love to choose it as the correct answer!

Comment: @AndrewRyan I am facing a new problem now. Would you please take a look at it during your free time?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77673255/model-trainer-issue-on-end-to-end-ml-project-typeerror-initiate-model-trainin