# Model Trainer Issue on End-to-End ML Project - TypeError: initiate_model_training() missing 4 required positional arguments

Tags: python, machine-learning, machine-learning-model

I am following the process shown on [Wine Quality Prediction End-to-End ML Project](https://youtu.be/pxk1Fr33-L4?si=zqJ_Ice6YT8pLYzJ) on Krish Naik's YouTube channel to do a Flight Fare Prediction Project.

I run this cell of model trainer pipeline on [04_model_trainer.ipynb](https://github.com/MdEhsanulHaqueKanan/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/blob/main/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb):

```
try:
    config = ConfigurationManager()
    model_trainer_config = config.get_model_trainer_config()
    model_trainer_config = ModelTrainer(model_trainer_config)
    # model_trainer_config.train()
    model_trainer_config.initiate_model_training()
except Exception as e:
    raise e
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: initiate_model_training() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'X_train', 'X_test', 'y_train', and 'y_test'
```

Here is the full traceback:

```
[2023-12-16 21:58:22,484: INFO: common: yaml file: config\config.yaml loaded successfully]
[2023-12-16 21:58:22,493: INFO: common: yaml file: params.yaml loaded successfully]
[2023-12-16 21:58:22,493: INFO: common: yaml file: schema.yaml loaded successfully]
[2023-12-16 21:58:22,493: INFO: common: created directory at: artifacts]
[2023-12-16 21:58:22,493: INFO: common: created directory at: artifacts/model_trainer]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[25], line 8
      6     model_trainer_config.initiate_model_training()
      7 except Exception as e:
----> 8     raise e

Cell In[25], line 6
      4     model_trainer_config = ModelTrainer(model_trainer_config)
      5     # model_trainer_config.train()
----> 6     model_trainer_config.initiate_model_training()
      7 except Exception as e:
      8     raise e

TypeError: initiate_model_training() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'X_train', 'X_test', 'y_train', and 'y_test'
```

Here is the code of `ModelTrainer` class:

```
class ModelTrainer:

    def __init__(self, model_trainer_config):
        self.model_trainer_config = model_trainer_config  
    # def __init__(self):
        # self.model_trainer_config = ModelTrainerConfig()    


    def save_obj(file_path, obj):
        try:

            dir_path = os.path.dirname(file_path)
            os.makedirs(dir_path, exist_ok=True)

            with open(file_path, 'wb') as file_obj:
                joblib.dump(obj, file_obj, compress= ('gzip'))

        except Exception as e:
            logger.info('Error occured in utils save_obj')
            raise e
        

    def evaluate_model(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, models):

        try:
            report = {}
            for i in range(len(models)):

                model = list(models.values())[i]

                # Train model
                model.fit(X_train,y_train)

                # Predict Testing data
                y_test_pred = model.predict(X_test)

                # Get R2 scores for train and test data
                test_model_score = r2_score(y_test,y_test_pred)

                report[list(models.keys())[i]] =  test_model_score

            return report

        except Exception as e:
            logger.info('Exception occured during model training')
            raise e    



    def initiate_model_training(self, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test):
        try:
            logger.info('Splitting ')

            models={
            'LinearRegression':LinearRegression(),
            'Lasso':Lasso(),
            'Ridge':Ridge(),
            'Elasticnet':ElasticNet(),
            'RandomForestRegressor': RandomForestRegressor(),
            'GradientBoostRegressor()' : GradientBoostingRegressor(),
            "AdaBoost" : AdaBoostRegressor(),
            'DecisionTreeRegressor' : DecisionTreeRegressor(),
            "SupportVectorRegressor" : SVR(),
            "KNN" : KNeighborsRegressor()
            }

            model_report:dict = ModelTrainer.evaluate_model(X_train,y_train, X_test, y_test, models)
            print(model_report)
            print("\n====================================================================================")
            logger.info(f'Model Report : {model_report}')

            # to get best model score from dictionary
            best_model_score = max(sorted(model_report.values()))

            best_model_name = list(model_report.keys())[
                list(model_report.values()).index(best_model_score)
            ]

            best_model = models[best_model_name]

            print(f"Best Model Found, Model Name :{best_model_name}, R2-score: {best_model_score}")
            print("\n====================================================================================")
            logger.info(f"Best Model Found, Model name: {best_model_name}, R2-score: {best_model_score}")
            logger.info(f"{best_model.feature_names_in_}")
            
            ModelTrainer.save_obj(
            file_path = self.model_trainer_config.trained_model_file_path,
            obj = best_model
            )

        except Exception as e:
            logger.info('Exception occured at model trianing')
            raise e
```

Here is [my file in GitHub](https://github.com/MdEhsanulHaqueKanan/Flight-Fare-Prediction-End-to-End-ML-Project/blob/main/research/04_model_trainer.ipynb).

My file encoding is UTF-8

Would you please help me to fix this issue?

Comment: When you call `model_trainer_config.initiate_model_training()` you need to pass in 4 variables `def initiate_model_training(self, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)` which the function definition is saying is required to run the function.

Comment: @AndrewRyan Yes, I know. But I am not sure how I pass these values. I mean aren't I supposed to pass the value to another function and then call these values to `initiate_model_training()` function? When I try to do that, I get errors.

Comment: @AndrewRyan In my working file, there are values for those 4 variables, which are commented. Here they are:
`X_train = train_data.drop([self.config.target_column], axis=1)`

`X_test = test_data.drop([self.config.target_column], axis=1)`

`y_train = train_data[[self.config.target_column]]`

`y_test = test_data[[self.config.target_column]]`

I am just not sure how to call them from the right function so that I don't get any error.

Comment: @AndrewRyan I am facing a new issue. Would you please take a look at it during your free time?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77691153/model-trainer-issue-on-end-to-end-ml-project-valueerror-at-least-one-array-or

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on the logic that you have in your jupyter notebook, you should likely have `initial_model_training()` modified to look like the below function:

```py
    def initiate_model_training(self): # removing the required variables to be passed into the function because those variables are created below (assuming they were correctly generated in train() )
        # lines below taken from your commented out train() function
        train_data = pd.read_csv(self.config.train_data_path)
        test_data = pd.read_csv(self.config.test_data_path)

        X_train = train_data.drop([self.config.target_column], axis=1)
        X_test = test_data.drop([self.config.target_column], axis=1)
        y_train = train_data[[self.config.target_column]]
        y_test = test_data[[self.config.target_column]]
        # lines above taken from your commented out train() function

        try:
            logger.info('Splitting ')

            models={
            'LinearRegression':LinearRegression(),
            'Lasso':Lasso(),
            'Ridge':Ridge(),
            'Elasticnet':ElasticNet(),
            'RandomForestRegressor': RandomForestRegressor(),
            'GradientBoostRegressor()' : GradientBoostingRegressor(),
            "AdaBoost" : AdaBoostRegressor(),
            'DecisionTreeRegressor' : DecisionTreeRegressor(),
            "SupportVectorRegressor" : SVR(),
            "KNN" : KNeighborsRegressor()
            }

            model_report:dict = ModelTrainer.evaluate_model(X_train,y_train, X_test, y_test, models)
            print(model_report)
            print("\n====================================================================================")
            logger.info(f'Model Report : {model_report}')

            # to get best model score from dictionary
            best_model_score = max(sorted(model_report.values()))

            best_model_name = list(model_report.keys())[
                list(model_report.values()).index(best_model_score)
            ]

            best_model = models[best_model_name]

            print(f"Best Model Found, Model Name :{best_model_name}, R2-score: {best_model_score}")
            print("\n====================================================================================")
            logger.info(f"Best Model Found, Model name: {best_model_name}, R2-score: {best_model_score}")
            logger.info(f"{best_model.feature_names_in_}")
            
            ModelTrainer.save_obj(
            file_path = self.model_trainer_config.trained_model_file_path,
            obj = best_model
            )

        except Exception as e:
            logger.info('Exception occured at model trianing')
            raise e
```

you should look through and understand how these https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c7k8i1l2X_r9i4yWAkQzxiP1Nu8_wqap/view these files work (from the tutorial that you are following), before you start to modify the code.

Comment: I am still getting the same error message after using your code.

Comment: I did look at the Google Drive link which you provided. I also completed the tutorial thoroughly while taking step by step notes. So, I did understand the code. However, the dataset that I am using for my project is quite different from the one used in the tutorial. The tutorial used a dataset that only had numerical values. But in my flight fare prediction dataset, there are many string values, which I had to transform into numerical values.

Comment: After using your code, it looks like the issue originates from the same last cell of the notebook file:

`try:
    config = ConfigurationManager()
    model_trainer_config = config.get_model_trainer_config()
    model_trainer_config = ModelTrainer(model_trainer_config)
    # model_trainer_config.train()
    model_trainer_config.initiate_model_training()`



I think we need to pass those four variables in `model_trainer_config.initiate_model_training()` in the right way.

Comment: Your solution has fixed the issue! Thank you very much!